# Query nested child sorted by date

Tags: javascript, firebase

Let's say I want to get the latest event from this Firebase data structure:

```
{
  events: {
    12345: {
      id: 12345,
      name: 'event1',
      date: '2016-12-30T00:00:00Z'
    },
    12346: {
      id: 12346,
      name: 'event2',
      date: '2016-12-20T00:00:00Z'
    },
    12347: {
      id: 12347,
      name: 'event3',
      date: '2016-12-10T00:00:00Z'
    }
  }
}
```

Is this possible or is my data structure wrong?

I've tried this without success.

```
firebase.database().ref('events').orderByChild('date').limitToLast(1).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
  return snapshot().val
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be returning it since it's done asynchronously:

```
firebase.database().ref('events').orderByChild('date').limitToLast(1).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
})
```